# Atary example from open ai install

Tags: python

I try to run this command

```
pip install cmake 'gym[atari]' scipy
```

But I receive this error:

> ERROR: Invalid requirement: ''gym[atari]''

I use cmd windows console.

What can I try to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [issue](https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/1218), you can see that "Sadly atari-py does not support windows to the best of my knowledge. You can try gym-retro though, which does: https://github.com/openai/retro".